Remove property and value from Response in Azure APIM Policy not on the top level
I have an Azure policy that has something similar to the following outbound response:
{
    "menu": null,
    "id": 101193,
    "value": [
        {
            "Description": "",
            "Properties": {
                "glossary": null,
                "data": []
            },
            "Acronym": 0
        },
        {
            "Description": "",
            "Properties": {
                "glossary": null,
                "data": []
            },
            "Acronym": 0
        },
        {
            "Description": "",
            "Properties": {
                "glossary": null,
                "data": []
            },
            "Acronym": 0
        }
       ],
    "alignment": null,
    "hOffset": null,
    "vOffset": false
}  

I would like to manipulate it with set-body to remove all the "glossary" properties and values so it looks like this:
{
    "menu": null,
    "id": 101193,
    "value": [
        {
            "Description": "",
            "Properties": {
                "data": []
            },
            "Acronym": 0
        },
        {
            "Description": "",
            "Properties": {
                "data": []
            },
            "Acronym": 0
        },
        {
            "Description": "",
            "Properties": {
                "data": []
            },
            "Acronym": 0
        }
       ],
    "alignment": null,
    "hOffset": null,
    "vOffset": false
}  

The documentation for removing a response in APIM has the following example. However this example only works for properties at the top level.
<!--  Copy this snippet into the outbound section to remove a number of data elements from the response received from the backend service based on the name of the product -->
<choose>
  <when condition="@(context.Response.StatusCode == 200 && context.Product.Name.Equals("Starter"))">
    <set-body>@{
        var response = context.Response.Body.As<JObject>();
        foreach (var key in new [] {"current", "minutely", "hourly", "daily", "alerts"}) {
          response.Property (key).Remove ();
        }
        return response.ToString();
      }
    </set-body>
  </when>
</choose>

I would like to be able to do something like this as it is in an APIM policy but with the glossary property. TIA for any help

I figured this out using JObject to a JArray and then converting back to an JOBject when iterating through each item of the array so I can access the remove property for that particular property. Solution is here:
https://dotnetfiddle.net/TDJ87v
